# URLImage on MapContainer not displayed on actual device and flickering in simulator

Tags: google-maps, codenameone

My app features a map, on which the user's avatar is displayed in the center and where markers including photo should be added when the user moves the map.

On the simulator, the markers are added but the images disappear as soon as I release the pointer then only the placeholders remain (this is what I call flickering). On the device, nothing is shown apart from the user's avatar.

[image: Markers with only the placeholder shown (user avatar's icon is further down)]

*As you can see the image does not remain on the map, only the placeholder does. The user icon is southern on the map but it is shown.*

Please note: I am not receiving 404 errors and there is only one listener on the map (see below):

Here is how I trigger the map update:

```
googleMap.addMapListener((source, zoom, center) -> {
                showReportsOnMap(googleMap, center, theme, currentForm, selectCategoryButton.getWidth());

});
```

And here is how I add the reports the map:

```
public void showReportsOnMap(
        MapContainer currentMap,
        Coord center,
        Resources theme,
        Form f,
        int reportImageWidth) {

    /**
     * Get the map borders (CAUTION : it can be NaN)
     */
    Coord NE = currentMap.getCoordAtPosition(currentMap.getAbsoluteX() + currentMap.getWidth(), currentMap.getAbsoluteY());
    Coord SW = currentMap.getCoordAtPosition(currentMap.getAbsoluteX(), currentMap.getAbsoluteY() + currentMap.getHeight());

    boolean bordersKnownAndValid = false;

    // Checks that the borders does not contain NaN as longitudes and latitudes
    if (!Double.isNaN(NE.getLatitude())
            && !Double.isNaN(NE.getLongitude())
            && !Double.isNaN(SW.getLatitude())
            && !Double.isNaN(SW.getLongitude())) {
        // The borders can be used
        bordersKnownAndValid = true;
    }

    if (bordersKnownAndValid) {
        ArrayList<Report> localReports = (ArrayList<Report>) (Report.getReportsWithinBoundingBounds(NE, SW, selectedCategoryIdToBeShownOnMap).get(1));

        // Revalidate only if we have something new to show
        if (localReports.size() > 0) {
            currentMap.clearMapLayers();
            currentMap.addMarker(ParametresGeneraux.getCurrentUser().getUserIcon(),
                    new Coord(ParametresGeneraux.getCurrentUser().getCurrentUserLocation().getLatitude(),
                            ParametresGeneraux.getCurrentUser().getCurrentUserLocation().getLongitude()),
                    ParametresGeneraux.getCurrentUser().getUserNickname(), "", null);

            Image tempPlaceholder = Image.createImage(
                    reportImageWidth,
                    reportImageWidth,
                    ParametresGeneraux.accentColor);
            Graphics gr = tempPlaceholder.getGraphics();
            gr.setAntiAliased(true);
            gr.setColor(ParametresGeneraux.accentColor);
            gr.fillArc(0, 0, reportImageWidth, reportImageWidth, 0, 360);

            EncodedImage roundPlaceholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(tempPlaceholder, true);

            // Add the report on the map
            for (Report report : localReports) {
                String photoFilenameInStorage = Report.getFilename(report.getPhotoPath())
                        + ParametresGeneraux.SUFFIX_ON_MAP_IMAGE;
                EncodedImage reportIcon = EncodedImage.createFromImage(URLImage.createToStorage(roundPlaceholder,
                        photoFilenameInStorage,
                        report.getPhotoPath(),
                        ParametresGeneraux.RESIZE_SCALE_WITH_ROUND_MASK
                ),
                        false); // we want transparency png otherwise it shows black edges

                currentMap.addMarker(reportIcon,
                        new Coord(report.getLocation().getLatitude(), report.getLocation().getLongitude()
                        ),
                        report.getCategory().getName(), "",
                        (evt) -> {
                            // Opens the detail form about this report
                            new ReportDetailsForm(theme, report, f.getClass()).show();
                        });
            }

            currentMap.setCameraPosition(new Coord(center.getLatitude(), center.getLongitude()));
            currentMap.zoom(new Coord(center.getLatitude(),
                    center.getLongitude()),
                    ParametresGeneraux.getUserZoomLevelOnMap());

            currentMap.animate();
            //f.forceRevalidate();
        }

    }

}
```

So I guess that the flickering in the simulator is a kind of slow motion of what happens on the device although the device does not show the placeholder.

What should I do to make the markers appear with an image?

**EDIT March 8th 2017**

On simulator, if I show a Dialog just before adding the marker to the map with this code :

```
Dialog.show("Photo", report.getAddress(), Dialog.TYPE_INFO, reportIcon, "OK", null);
```

The icon is well displayed in the Dialog (see screen capture below)

[image: The Dialog shows the image]

and then the image appears on the map without flickering any more as depicted below :

[image: Afterwards the image remains on the map]

However on an actual Android device even the Dialog does not appear.

Finally I don't know why the Dialog makes then the markers behave as expected on the simulator but not on the device, so I am a bit at lost!

Any help would be precious.

Comment: When did you install the cn1lib and which version is it? We released a new update late last week and it might have regressions or these might be bugs related to the new version. We'll post a blog entry discussing this next week

Comment: Regarding the simulator behaviour it is not new. It has always behaved like this since Jan/Feb 2017. I did not pay attention because I thought it was a little bug on the simulatore. On the real device I can't remember. The GoogleMaps.cn1lib I use is the version 6 (December 8th 2016). Maybe it is worth it updating it!

Comment: I tried your suggestion (used downloadImageToStorage()) with cn1libs GoogleMaps Version 6 and the images still flickered in the simulator (appeared when I pressed the pointer, left when I released it). Now that I've upgraded to version 10, the images do not even appear. But @Shai told there were regressions (as on the actual device). Should I give up until version 11 is released ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that URLImage may not have finished downloading by the time you added it as a marker.  If you call `EncodedImage.createFromImage(urlImage)` before URLImage has finished downloading, then you'll be creating an encoded image of the urlImage's placeholder.

the `com.codename1.io.Util` class includes quite a few methods for downloading images from URLs.  Some are blocking, and some use a callback. Either way you just need to ensure that the image is actually downloaded before adding it to a map.

NOTE: Normally this wouldn't be an issue with URLImage - e.g. if you were adding it to a Button or a Label.  It is only a problem here because the MapContainer is native, and it actually needs to pass the image data to the native layer at the time that `setMarker()` is called.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, it helps me better understand. I'll have a look at all that! I'll keep you posted.

Comment: I tried your suggestion (used downloadImageToStorage()) with cn1libs GoogleMaps Version 6 and the images still flickered in the simulator (appeared when I pressed the pointer, left when I released it). Now that I've upgraded to version 10, the images do not even appear. But @Shai told there were regressions. Should I give up until version 11 is released ?

Comment: I also tried to `addMarker()` with an image from the theme.res file instead of the downloaded image and the image did not show. However if Ido not add the user icon in the first time, and add the report images, then the report images appear but only one at a time. So it looks like images from the local source gets precedence over downloaded images, and that only one image can be displayed at a time. Am I right ?

Comment: Version 6 is very old.  It's at version 12 now.
Local images/ remove images, etc.. get no "precedence".  I have maps with dozens of markers and different images, so you can display more than one at a time.

Comment: Is version 12 already released ? When I do "Codename One settings / Extensions / Google native maps support" there is a check. And Netbeans show a file "GoogleMaps.ver" in the "lib" dir which has `version=10` in it. Anyway I must be doing something wrong (maybe using a layered layout with the map, or using simultaneously a FAB on the form). I'll with a bare bone map.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a bit of your code with markers on map ? I tried both the blocking `downloadImageToStotage(placeholder, path, true` and with the callback but the markers do not show up. I added an `InfiniteProgress` around the blocking one, and I can see the spinning wheel and the screen going greyer on the simulator but not on the device. Snippets would be very appreciated ;-)!

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps/blob/master/GoogleMapsTest/src/com/codename1/test/googlemaps/GoogleMapsTestApp.java#L77-L112) is an example using a FontImage. Don't have one handy with URLImage, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Thanks @Steve. The difference between your code and mine is that you don't use `clearMapLayers()` before you add a marker. But in my case if the user select the same location several times, then the same marker image will be drawn several time. So the map will become slugish, won't it ?  Or I shouldn't add the marker if it has already been drans ?

Comment: Hi @Steve, eventually found out who the culprit was! I can't remember why I declared the `MapContainer` `static`. Therefore going back to the form containing the map did not launch the `MapListener` and hence my method to draw the markers ;-)